# Jquery, getting input value with a variable

Tags: jquery, post, checkbox

I have an post action, and when it success, i call a method and pass a the json result. Then i loop through each json object, in that loop i want to get a checkbox with objects id as a value attribute, here is how i did:

```
$.each(roles, function (index, role) {
        var checkboxes = $('input[value="role.RoleId"][type="checkbox"]').attr("checked",true);



    });
```

As you can see, i have a list of checkboxes and i want to select them when their value attribute is equal to "role.RoleId". But i couldn't manage to do it, how can i do it?

Edit: Well how can i select the wrapper element of that checkbox. it's in . so i need also select  element?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the value or role.RoleId like this

```
 var checkboxes = $('input[value="'+role.RoleId+'"][type="checkbox"]').attr("checked",true);
```

as role is a object from $.each loop.

Comment: well how can i select the wrapper element of that checkbox. it's in <span><input type="checkbox"></span>. so i need also select <span> element?

Comment: @mehmetserif If you have other needs, please edit your question.

Comment: @mehmetserif You should post that as a new question if it is completly different question from what you have asked here.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

```
.prop("checked",true);
```

Also you need to append the role.RoleId.. see below,

```
$.each(roles, function (index, role) {
        var checkboxes = $('input:checkbox[value="' + role.RoleId + '"]').prop("checked",true);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/7yvGR/)

Comment: Ok but,is "input[value="role.RoleId"]" correct? i mean role.RoleId is the result from the post action.

Comment: @mehmetserif mm let me test and see. but you need to use `.prop` also you can use `input:checkbox[..]` instead of `type="checkbox"`

Answer (score 0):

```
 var checkboxes = $('input[value="'+role.RoleId+'"][type="checkbox"]').prop("checked",true);
```

But set ids to the checkboxes will make problem more simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:checkbox` selector to shorten your code up just a bit:

```
$(":checkbox[value=" + role.RoleId + "]").prop("checked", true);
```

You want to use concatenation here so that `role.RoleId` isn't interpreted literally, as plain text, but instead we want to use the *value* of `role.RoleId`.